# Unity Scene Files not transferring properly through TFS between Windows and OSX

Tags: windows, macos, unity-game-engine, tfs

This is a strange circumstance that my boss and I just got into this morning as we were trying to import my scene from the Team Foundation Server to his machine. I created a Unity Scene file and made my scene over the course of the past month or so and when I was finished I uploaded everything to TFS so he could pull it down and use it (we are quite far apart from each other so we can't just usb drive everything over to see what the problem might be). When he pulled the scene file down (and all the supporting scripts) one of the scripts that was in the scene was changed. It started out being a script called Smart_HUD4 but when he went in to the inspector the script was now called Smart_HUD2 and was an entirely different script than what I had written, not to mention I don't even have a Smart_HUD2 script on my machine. The same also applied to another script called laser (now called Laser1 and again, not something I wrote nor is it on my machine).

Has anyone else come up against a problem like this? Found any solutions? It's strange because I went ahead a re-downloaded the files I uploaded and everything was exactly how it was supposed to be, proper names and scripts in their proper places. We think the issue is because we are moving from Windows to OSX and the differences in operating systems might be leaving behind some residual code or something that is causing things to be switched around?

TFS never asked me to merge any files so if it is the case that TFS might be auto-merging files, none of the files its merging even share the same name, its just picking ones whose names are close and doing so (the scene file's name was completely unique so it has nothing to merge that with).

Comment: TFS won't change your files. Have you checked the history of your files in TFS?

Answer (score 0):

OK, few things to check:

1. Have you checked that the files do not exist in the TFS with similar naming? regardless of TFS requesting name changes?
2. do you have any other projects effected?
3. Have you checked (I'm guessing you have) that the unity versions are matching exactly?

Now, something to consider, The unity system does vary between Windows and MacOS, mainly in the fact that Unity Makes use windows bases features that are not present on a Mac and this can cause file issues.

When moving between systems, Unity packages the scene data on windows in a global and local format. So, sometimes folder structure can change.

From experience, the most likely issue is more to do with file locations than OS discrepancies, as it might have been a clash between your project and other similar.

Remote file management is odd at times when doing colab stuff. Have you checked with other colleagues made sure they don't have anything similar uploading?

But, scripts changing names and data is not something that I would expect. So my guess is that the issue lies with the upload on the TFS and not the MacOS vs Windows move.

Hope this helps,

Glenn